# Match path prefix and replace all delimiters

Tags: sed

I would like to match a path prefix and replace all delimiters using `sed`.

Consider the following example strings and the desired results. The path prefix is `one/two` and the delimiter is forward slash.

```
one/two/three.Something => one.two.three.Something
one/two/three/four/five.Another => one.two.three.four.five.Another
```

So far I've come up with this command

```
echo one/two/three.Something | sed 's/one\/two\(.*\)\./one.two\1./g'
```

How do I make it produce the results above, can this be done with `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`, you may use

```
sed ':a; s~^\(one\)[/.]\(two[^.]*\)/~\1.\2.~; ta;' file;
```

*One caveat*: it will also match `one.two` prefixed lines.

Or, you may also use

```
sed 's/^one\/two[^.]*/&\n/;h;y/\//./;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

This correctly handles only `one/two` prefixed lines.

The first `sed` command means:

- `:a` - sets an `a` label
- `s~^\(one\)[/.]\(two[^.]*\)/~\1.\2.~`  - finds the following:

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\(one\)` - Group 1 (`\1`): `one` word
  - `[/.]` - a `/` or `.`
  - `\(two[^.]*\)` - Group 2: `two`, then 0+ chars other than `.` and then
  - `/` - a `/` char
- `\1.\2.` - Replaces with Group 1 value + `.` + Group 2 value + `.`
- `ta` - loop to `:a` label if there was a match at the preceding iteration.

The second sed command means

- `s/^one\/two[^.]*/&\n/` - replace `one/two` + 0 or more chars other than `.` with the same value (`&`)  and append a newline
- `h` - copies the pattern buffer into the hold buffer while  keeping the pattern buffer unchanged
- `y/\//./` - replaces each `/` with `.`
- `G` - append hold space to the pattern space
- `s/\n.*\n//` - remove the redundant text between two introduced newlines.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/d7SsAs):

```
tests="one/two/three.Something one/two/three/four/five.Another"
for test in $tests; do
  sed ':a; s~^\(one\)[/.]\(two[^.]*\)/~\1.\2.~; ta;' <<< "$test";
  sed 's/^one\/two[^.]*/&\n/;h;y/\//./;G;s/\n.*\n//' <<< "$test"
done;
```

Output:

```
one.two.three.Something
one.two.three.four.five.Another
```

Comment: This is probably the right answer considering the question is about sed. Any idea how to make it work in other versions beside GNU sed? And the demo above works great for lines, however, is it possible to make it replace paths anywhere in a text file?

Comment: @mozey Try `sed -e ':a' -e 's~\(one\)[/.]\(two[^.]*\)/~\1.\2.~' -e 'ta' file`. The second solution that is more precise will probably fail in non-GNU seds due to the replacement with `\n`, although you might try to type a literal newline there. I can't test non-GNU sed solutions, I have no access to such environments.

Comment: The example in your last comment using `-e` works on the macOS version of `sed`, but the same commands terminated with `;` does not. If I use the `-e` options, it then complains when I use `-i` to replace the file inline. Maybe I'm putting the `-i` in the wrong place

Comment: @mozey It should be `sed -i.bak -e ':a' -e 's~\(one\)[/.]\(two[^.]*\)/~\1.\2.~' -e 'ta' file`. Do not use semi-colons in a FreeBSD `sed` command to separate its parts. `-i.bak` should precede `-e`, after `-e` all the commands start. If you do not want to save a backup, use `-i ''` (`sed -i '' -e ':a'...`).

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was just thinking it might be missing the backup file extension. This works for me, I'm trying to replace a bunch of paths in a generated JSON file

Comment: @mozey Eventually, use `perl`: `perl -i -pe 's|one/two[^.]*|$&=~s!/!.!gr|ge' file`, see [this online demo](https://ideone.com/F1hFXP). It is precise and simple.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/one\/two.*Something||\/one\/two.*Another/{gsub(/\//,".")} 1' Input_file
```

This will look for string `one/two` till either `something` or `Another` and replace all `/` with `.` in that line.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed level explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                           ##Starting awk program from here.
/one\/two.*Something||\/one\/two.*Another/{     ##Checking condition if a line has one/two till Something OR one/two till Another then do following.
  gsub(/\//,".")                                ##Using global substitution to substitute all / with DOT
}
1                                               ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
'  Input_file                                   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: "substitute anything apart from digits and alphabets" No, it has to match the path prefix, and replace delimiters in the matching snippet only up to the ".Something" or ".Another" extension

Comment: @mozey, Could you please try my edited command now and lemme know if that helps you?

Comment: Thanks, this solution works great if I'm going to use awk. I also simplified your pattern to this: `awk '/one\/two.*\./{gsub(/\//,".")} 1'`

Comment: @mozey, Sure, thanks for sharing. I also added detailed level explanation of my solution, cheers.

Comment: Great. The awk syntax is simpler. I'm trying to fix paths in a JSON file that is generated by another program, and I want to do the replacement inside a Makefile. Too bad `awk` doesn't have an `-i` option like `sed`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#one/two/\S\+#echo "&"|sed "s:/:.:g"#eg' file
```

This solution calls a second invocation of sed within the RHS of a substitution. The first substitution extracts the path, the second echo's that result into another invocation of sed that replaces the `/`'s with `.`'s.

N.B. The substitutions can be applied globally throughout the file.